# multi-line statements in REBOL?

Tags: rebol, rebol3, rebol2

An annoying problem I'm having with the REBOL3 REPL is that it won't accept multi-line statements. For instance, I would like to type "some_obj: make obj! [" , hit enter, and then continue the statement.

This is relevant for me as I am using a Vim plugin that sends visually selected source code to the REPL.

I have read on another StackOverflow question that REBOL2 supports multi-line statements, while REBOL3 does not. Has anyone provided a fix for this, or is there a fork with a multi-line support in the REPL?

Comment: Mainline Rebol3 is not scheduled for good multi-line input, but Red supports it today.  However... the future may not be so grim... see [Ren Garden](https://youtu.be/0exDvv5WEv4?t=803) for "more than just multi-line" :-)

Comment: Note: I upvoted you to try and help you [get enough points to chat](http://rebolsource.net/go/chat-faq) where you can have this and your other questions about "what's going on?" answered.  However I'm also voting to close.  Project roadmap questions aren't "good SO questions".  *(SO kind of puts us [between a rock and a hard place on that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257949/room-owners-should-be-allowed-to-accept-20-rep-users-to-talk-in-a-room).)*

Comment: @HostileFork Well thanks for the points :), I've been trying to get enough points to ask questions on the chat.

Comment: Looks like you got your bump.  First time's free. :-)  Come join...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Rebol 3 Console doesn't support multi line statements.

I usually write my statements into a text editor, copy them to clipboard and then do in Rebol3 console:

```
do to string! read clipboard://
```

Better put that into a function:

```
do-clip: does [do to string! read clipboard://]
```

Comment: Yeah...hm but I'm working on a remote VM, so clipboard is not readily accessible to me.

I'm thinking about modifying Vim SLIME to do something like what you suggested.